# Delphi xe5: Update 1 messed up virtual keyboard

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

After the latest update to Delphi xe5: Help Update 1, all of my newly compiled programs are having layout issues with the virtual keyboard (using iOS)... The toolbar containing the 'done' button is half hidden by the keyboard itself. This is apparent on all machines with the new update applied so I know this is not due to a corrupt download or something I did.

Has anyone found a work-around to fix this ?

[image]

UPDATE! Still no resolution. My keyboard now looks like this (^^^^) on all of my newly compiled apps as well as my old ones that did work correctly. Anyway to fix this ?

Comment: Did you update XCode since you built it last (Try building it on XCode 4)?

Comment: Xcode was on the same update as before I did the Delphi Update, and I've also just updated XCode as well. It's not Xcode.

Comment: They did 'fix' something with that 'Done button' in XE5, which seems to have reverted: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/43359 but I cannot find more details in Quality Central (that ID cannot be found). Another virtual keyboard issue does not seem related http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=119353

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article which deals with the issue and offers some solutions:

http://delphi.radsoft.com.au/2013/10/coping-with-the-virtual-keyboard-done-bar-and-clicking-controls-on-the-ios7-simulator/